# JPA 2 Criteria ManyToMany Subselect

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I have the following scenario:

Person.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_person", sequenceName = "seq_person", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_pessoa")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.REFRESH, javax.persistence.CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "person_category", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id") })
    protected List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}
```

Category.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_category", sequenceName = "seq_category", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_category")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

With this scenario, I need to do a query using JPA2 Criteria, to substitute this HQL query:

```
SELECT obj FROM Person AS obj
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT category.id FROM obj.categories AS category
    WHERE category.name = 'Staff'
)
```

I've tried to make a join with categories, but it multiply the result by the quantity of categories of each person:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> cq = cb.createQuery(Person.class);

Root<Person> root = cq.from(Person);

cq.select(root);

Subquery<Category> subquery = cq.subquery(Category.class);
Root<Category> subqueryFrom = subquery.from(Category.class);
subquery.select(subquery.from(clazz).get("id"));

Predicate predicateJoin = cb.equal(root.join("categories", JoinType.LEFT), subqueryFrom);
Predicate predicateName = cb.like(subqueryFrom.get("name"), "%" + content + "%");

subquery.where(cb.and(predicateJoin, predicateName));
cb.where(cb.exists(subquery));

TypedQuery<Person> typedQuery = this.entityManager.createQuery(cq);

List<Person> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

This criteria result in this SQL:

```
select
    person0_.id as id1_50_,
    person0_.name as name29_50_
from
    person person0_ 
left outer join
    person_category categories2_ 
        on person0_.id=categories2_.person_id 
left outer join
    category categoryp3_ 
        on categories2_.category_id=categoryp3_.id 
where
    exists (
        select
            categoryp5_.id 
        from
            person_category categoryp4_ cross 
        join
            person_category categoryp5_ 
        where
            categoryp3_.id=categoryp4_.id 
            and (
                categoryp4_.name like ?
            )
    )
```

The generated SQL do a CROSS JOIN with `person_category` and do the LEFT JOIN out of subselect.

Using the HQL Hibernate produces the following SQL:

```
select
    person0_.id as id1_50_,
    person0_.name as name29_50_
from
    person person0_ 
where
    exists (
        select
            categoryp2_.id 
        from
            person_category categories1_,
            category categoryp2_ 
        where
            person0_.id=categories1_.person_id 
            and categories1_.category_id=categoryp2_.id 
            and categoryp2_.name=?
    )
```

How I can do this query in Criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `correlate()` the outer query with the subquery. Try something along the following lines (it is hard to test without having the real model, but should be close enough):

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Person> cq = cb.createQuery(Person.class);

    Root<Person> root = cq.from(Person.class);

    cq.select(root);

    Subquery<Category> subquery = cq.subquery(Category.class);
    Root<Person> subqueryRoot = subquery.correlate(root);
    Join<Person,Category> personCategories = subqueryRoot.join("categories");
    subquery
        .select(personCategories) // check out comment for possible needed change
        .where(cb.equal(personCategories.get("name"), "Staff"));
    
    cq.where(cb.exists(subquery));

    TypedQuery<Person> typedQuery = this.entityManager.createQuery(cq);

    List<Person> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

This *should* result in:

```
SELECT obj FROM Person AS obj
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT category FROM obj.categories AS category
    WHERE category.name = 'Staff'
)
```

Comment: It works! The only change I made was in `subquery.select(personCategories)`, to `subquery.select(subqueryRoot.get("id"))` and now works perfectly.